# How to change central meridian of world map json file?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, d3.js, geojson

I've loaded a json file of a world map and am using d3. However, part of Russia is on the opposite side of the map, next to Alaska.

The json file was created from a shapefile that I exported as unprojected (WGS84)

Is there a way to change the central meridian so that Russia isn't split?
I've tried changing the center in d3, but it hasn't worked.

Code for reference:

```
d3.json("data/world.json", function (error, myMap) {

    if (error) return console.error(errorMap);
    var myMapFeatures = topojson.feature(myMap, myMap.objects.world);

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([30,39])
        .scale(width*.10)
        .translate([width/2, height/2]);
    var geoProjectionPath = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(myMapFeatures.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { 
        return "country " + d.properties.Terr_Name; 
        })
    .attr("d", geoProjectionPath);
```

})

Comment: Can you post your code? Without knowing what exactly you did it's impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that with the help of `rotate` on projection

```
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
 .center([30,39])
.scale(100)
.rotate([-90,0]);//this will make Russia unsplit
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEom1WlD4IoucjHzEvOi?p=preview)

Comment: Really appreciate the response @Cyril
Is it possible to scale the map down within the 'frame' to have the entire world map show in the viewport?
I adjusted .scale, but it scales down the entire frame instead of just the map within the frame.

Comment: use `equirectangular` as shown in my answer. Kindly accept it if this answers your question this is how it works http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work